# Moving folders if they or their subfolders contain specific files (bash)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix

I am new to bash scripting and stackoverflow (first question). I am trying to do a fairly simple thing but I am somehow not getting what I want (tried to use some of the solutions from different threads but with no luck). Perhaps you can help me with a simple solution.

My task: Look through different folders (in some main folder) for for a file named log.txt. If found then move the relevant folder to another location (its a backup folder...the log.txt indicates that this folder needs a backup). In the below layout, I want to mv folder3 along with all its content.

```
-Main
--folder1   
  ---subfolder
--folder2
  ---Subfolder2
--folder3   
   --Subfolder3
        --log.txt

#!/bin/bash
MAIN=$(find /home/rwo/Desktop/FROM/* -maxdepth 0 -type d)
for FOLDER in $MAIN; do
        if 
            find $FOLDER -maxdepth 0 -type f -name "log.txt" 
                then
                    mv $FOLDER /home/rwo/Desktop/TO

        fi
done
```

In the above case, the recipient folder (TO) ends up receiving Subfolder1, Subfolder2 and Subfolder3 (along with log.txt). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `find` has `-regex` - with that you can just match `log.txt`

Comment: hmm, would you mind showing me how to use it (in the above context). I have never used -regex and I don't find the syntax that easy to understand

Comment: `find` returns with "success" (exit status 0) even if no file was found, so your code will always execute the `then` clause.

Answer (score 1):

With `find` and `bash`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r file; do
  file=${file%/*}
  echo mv -v "${file%/*}" /home/rwo/Desktop/TO
done < <(find main -type f -name 'log.txt')
```

The `echo` is there to show you what's going to happen, remove it if you think the output is ok.

---

A simple simulation

```
mkdir -p Main/folder{1..3}
mkdir -p Main/folder1/subfolder
mkdir -p Main/folder2/subfolder2
mkdir -p Main/folder3/subfolder3
touch Main/folder3/subfolder3/log.txt
```

Create the destination directory

```sh
mkdir -p home/rwo/Desktop/TO
```

check the what is inside the Main directory.

```
tree Main
```

Output

```
Main
├── folder1
│   └── subfolder
├── folder2
│   └── subfolder2
└── folder3
    └── subfolder3
        └── log.txt

6 directories, 1 file
```

Now the script to match the Main

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r file; do
  file=${file%/*}
  echo mv -v "${file%/*}" home/rwo/Desktop/TO
done < <(find Main -type f -name 'log.txt')
```

output

```
mv -v Main/folder3/ home/rwo/Desktop/TO
```

Removing the `echo` will output

```
renamed 'Main/folder3/' -> 'home/rwo/Desktop/TO/folder3'
```

The `"${file%/*}"` is form of [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) Which basically removes the last `/`

So for example the output of `find main -type f -name 'log.txt'`

```
main/folder3/subfolder3/log.txt
```

Removing the last `/` with parameter expansion will leave just the path name

```
main/folder3/subfolder3/
```

Apply another parameter expansion to remove the last `/` will result to

```
main/folder3/
```

Then feeding that to `mv` as an argument inside the `while read` loop.

The `<()` 
is called [Process Substituion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

The `IFS=` disables the default feature of the builtin `read` which removes the trailing and leading white spaces.

Have a look at [howto read a file or stream in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) to understand the `while read` loop that is posted.

Comment: I am getting this (if I just remove the echo and leave the main variable defined as shown in my first question): mv: cannot move '/home/rwo/Desktop/FROM/B/subfolder' to 'home/rwo/Desktop/TO': No such file or directory

Comment: I posted a sample of what the script is doing, maybe you can follow it in some empty directory to see what is going on. Also I think you need a leading `/` in the destination directory. e.g. `/home/rwo/Desktop/TO`

Comment: @Sumsarium without the leading `/` in the directory name that means it is the current working directory or folder in Windows term.

Comment: Awesome. It has almost solved my task, except that it moves "subfolder3". I also want to move folder3. If i need a quick fix for this? I promise to read up on Parameter Expansion.

Comment: Add `file=${file%/*}` just below the line where the `do` is and don't remove the echo just yet, so you can see if that is what you wanted to happen.

Comment: That did nothing. The script did not execute (and nothing from echo)

Comment: Are you sure you still have the correct folder structure? Do the simulation again and add the code I gave you.

Comment: @Sumsarium, I have updated the answer to your requirements, sorry about that.

Comment: I worked perfectly for the specific case. Thank you very much (kudos!). I am trying to understand the syntax and have a last question: what if you want to make it more generic, i.e. you have an unknown folder-structure (number of folders), i.e. instead of Main/folder3/subfolder3/log.txt you might have something like Main/.../folder3/subfolder3/log.txt (... = some number of folders).

Comment: just adding that "Main" is the only foldername that is fixed

Comment: `find` is recursive by default, it goes down as deep as your directory structure and finds what you want to told it to find, unless you have the `max` and `min` added.

Comment: Yes and the output is, in this case, also correct. However if I added extra folders on top of  "folder3", e.g. Main/folder_i+1/folder_i+2/folder_i+n/folder3/Subfolder3/log.txt, then the output in "TO" (receiving folder) would be folder3/Subfolder3/log.txt instead of folder_i+1/folder_i+2/folder_i+n/folder3/Subfolder3/log.txt. I think I need to change the parameter extension but am not sure about the syntax